# ActiveAdmin Redirect After Create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In activeadmin, I would like to know how to redirect to an url with a parameter after a record is created?

So far I have the following code which works except 'event_id' is empty.

**Eg:**

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/events/new?event_id=369877
```

**Code**

```
  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        parameters = Rack::Utils.parse_query URI(request.referrer).query
        format.html { redirect_to '/admin/events?q[espn_event_id_equals]='+ parameters['espn_event_id'].to_s }
      end
    end
  end
```

**It rediects to:**

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/events?q[event_id_equals]=
```

**instead of**

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/events?q[event_id_equals]=369877
```

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION**

The solution was to parse the URL from request.referrer to get the desired parameter.

```
  controller do
    def create
      create! do |format|
        parameters = Rack::Utils.parse_query URI(request.referrer).query
        format.html { redirect_to '/admin/events?q[espn_event_id_equals]='+ parameters['espn_event_id'].to_s }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks for the suggestions : )

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Did any of the answers below work?

Comment: Thanks, The solution has been posted : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try keying the param to a symbol, rather than a string:

```
format.html { redirect_to '/admin/events?q[event_id_equals]='+ params[:event_id].to_s }
```

If that doesn't work, it means (more likely than not) that `params[:event_id]` is `nil`. Because `nil.to_s` is an empty string, you're not seeing anything being appended to the specified path.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you structure is a bit confusing. But I think this is pretty straight forward:

```
format.html { redirect_to admin_events_path(q[event_id_equals]: params[:event_id]) }
```

if this doesn't work, that's probably because it can't read `q[event_id_equals]` as a symbol, in this case you shoudl try: `admin_events_path("q[event_id_equals]" => params[:event_id])`

There are probably better ways of naming and controlling this, but this will certainly fix things for you.

For active_admin 1.0.0.pre2:

```
format.html { redirect_to admin_events_path('q[event_id_eq]': params[:event_id]) }
```

Comment: For active_admin 1.0.0.pre2, the parameter should be 'q[event_id_eq]' instead.